# FFMPEG iPhone using gas-preprocessor

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, for-loop

I got the latest version of FFMPEG and gas-preprocessor, and i am trying to build them libraries for iPhone. I put the gas-preprocessor.pl file in my usr/bin folder, and try to configure my ffmpeg with this command.

./configure --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1 --as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.2.1' --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.sdk --enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic

But what i get is this error

Unknown option "--as=gas-preprocessor.pl".
See ./configure --help for available options.

Any ideas??? Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

you need to **create** folders **in usr dir** called **local** and then **bin** then **in bin put** gas-preprocessor.pl file.

then try the configure command.

Note: by default usr dir which is in root level is hidden,
you need to right click on finder icon, select "Go to Folder" then type /usr and enter to reveal usr directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move or copy gas-preprocessor into /usr/local/bin directory. Note that you must be root user to copy this file into this directory. (By default root user is not activated on mac, you have to activate it before).

Hope it helps,
David